# $u=\sum (u,\varphi_k)_{L^2}\varphi_k$ vs $u(x)=\sum (u,\varphi_k)_{L^2}\varphi_k(x)$ and related questions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

I have some doubts after reading several threads.

Let us work on a bounded domain $\Omega$ with Neumann BCs, with $\varphi_k$ and $\lambda_k$ being the orthonormalised eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the Neumann Laplacian. If $u \in L^2(\Omega)$, then
$$u=\sum (u,\varphi_k)_{L^2}\varphi_k.\tag{1}$$
According to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209900/uniform-convergence-of-fourier-orthonormal-expansion-of-series), (1) does NOT imply in general that
$$u(x) = \sum (u,\varphi_k)_{L^2}\varphi_k(x)$$
holds for a.e $x$, which really surprises me.  If it does hold and if the convergence is not uniform, then we cannot integrate term by term for example or anything like that.

However, in papers (like [this one](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7406v3.pdf), see top of page 7), I have seen authors **defining**
$$v(x,y) = \sum e^{-\lambda_k y}(u,\varphi_k)\varphi_k(x)$$
and this confuses me because well in what sense is this sum defined, given what I said above? This function $v$ is supposed to solve $v_{yy} + \Delta_x v=0$ with trace $v_{y=0}=u$ in a weak sense. In the above paper the author freely manipulates $v$ by differentiating and integrating etc.

But I cannot establish uniform continuity in $x$ which one needs for this solution to make sense. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the $L^{2}$ norm means that you can interchange summation and integration. For example, if $f \in L^{2}$, then
$$
         \int_{\Omega} f\sum_{k}(u,\varphi_{k})\varphi_{k}dx = \sum_{k}(u,\varphi_{k})\int_{\Omega}f\varphi_{k}
$$
This is because, if $g_{n}\rightarrow g$ in $L^{2}$, then
$$
         \lim_{n}\int_{\Omega}fg_{n}dx = \int_{\Omega}fgdx
$$
because
$$
      \left|\int_{\Omega}fg_{n}dx-\int_{\Omega}fgdx\right| 
      = \left|\int_{\Omega}f(g_n-g)dx\right|\le \|f\|\|g_n-g\|\rightarrow 0.
$$
Convergence in integral gives you a lot.